# How do i get pem file or generate pem file from github's client secret ? Here is below img attached below

Tags: github, github-api, github-actions, github-app

[image]

Here is my secret from which I want to generate pem file. which I want to use for authenticating GitHub API to generate accessToken.

Answer (score 0):

You don't? The way I know how to do it is to generate a private key and then use that to grab temporary (1 hour) PATs when you need them. To do that, you need to use special JWT tokens for the first few calls to the API - to discover the URL to get the access token and then to call that. This is described, for python, in https://gist.github.com/pelson/47c0c89a3522ed8da5cc305afc2562b0, although I used pyjwt and the required instructions were seemingly slightly different.